# IFTTT-style trigger for receiving texts?

Tags: iphone, sms, ios

What I would like to do is configure my phone so that whenever I receive a text from a specific group chat, my phone automatically texts itself the message in a different format. My phone is an iPhone 5, and my carrier is AT&T. As far as I know, IFTTT doesn't have anything quite like this, so is there a way I can do this?

Comment: This seems to be an iPhone problem to solve, not a web application problem. You should ask at [apple.se]. (I suggest you leave out the bit about IFTTT and just ask how you can auto-forward modified SMS.)

Comment: @AlE. ifttt is clearly a webapp, and supports this feature on Android but not yet on iPhones.